# Error with autotest in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, railstutorial.org, autotest

I ran the command autotest and this is the error I got . I am following Hartl's book and was wondering is this clash happening because rails now comes with ZenTest or something else ? How can I work past this error. I am new to RoR

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
/Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find ZenTest (>= 0) amongst [abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.2.8, actionmailer-3.2.8.rc1, actionmailer-3.0.1, actionmailer-3.0.0, actionpack-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8.rc1, actionpack-3.0.1, actionpack-3.0.0, activemodel-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8.rc1, activemodel-3.0.1, activemodel-3.0.0, activerecord-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8.rc1, activerecord-3.0.1, activerecord-3.0.0, activeresource-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8.rc1, activeresource-3.0.1, activeresource-3.0.0, activesupport-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8.rc1, activesupport-3.0.1, activesupport-3.0.0, addressable-2.3.2, arel-3.0.2, arel-1.0.1, autotest-4.4.6, builder-3.0.4, builder-3.0.3, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.2.1, bundler-1.2.0, bundler-1.0.22, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.4.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, excon-0.16.2, execjs-1.4.0, heroku-2.31.2, heroku-api-0.3.5, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.1, i18n-0.4.2, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.1.4, jquery-rails-2.1.2, json-1.7.5, launchy-2.1.2, mail-2.4.4, mail-2.2.19, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.4.0, multi_json-1.3.6, netrc-0.7.7, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-1.2.5, rack-cache-1.2, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.2.8, rails-3.2.8.rc1, rails-3.0.1, railties-3.2.8, railties-3.2.8.rc1, railties-3.0.1, railties-3.0.0, rake-10.0.2, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, rest-client-1.6.7, rspec-2.12.0, rspec-core-2.12.1, rspec-expectations-2.12.0, rspec-mocks-2.12.0, rspec-rails-2.12.0, rubygems-bundler-1.1.0, rubyzip-0.9.9, rvm-1.11.3.5, sass-3.2.3, sass-3.2.1, sass-rails-3.2.5, sequel-3.20.0, sinatra-1.0, spork-0.9.2, spork-0.9.0, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, taps-0.3.24, thor-0.16.0, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.12, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.35, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.3.0] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/autotest:18:in `<main>'
from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

So after the answer suggested , I tried to uninstall Zentest first

```
-MacBook-Pro:proto1 $ gem uninstall ZenTest-4.8.4
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
INFO:  gem "ZenTest-4.8.4" is not installed
```

After this ( inspite of the error messages , I installed the downgrade version )

```
s-MacBook-Pro:proto1 $ gem install ZenTest --version "=4.8.3"
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Fetching: ZenTest-4.8.3.gem (100%)
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Successfully installed ZenTest-4.8.3
1 gem installed
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Installing ri documentation for ZenTest-4.8.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for ZenTest-4.8.3...
```

And then I run autotest with this showing up !

```
s-MacBook-Pro:proto1 $ autotest
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
loading autotest/rspec2
```

New part of the problem :

After I was suggested to delete ZenTest gemspec file , I cannot run spork or the rails server . I have installed ZenTest 4.8.3 but it's showing the following thing :

```
$ spork
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Could not find ZenTest-4.8.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the command `autotest` you have to install the `ZenTest` gem.
I think you had installed `ZenTest 4.8.4` in your system. this gem is not working properly.
So you have to downgrade it to **4.8.3**. Remove all the the files related to `ZenTest 4.8.4`. then install **4.8.3** using the command

`gem install ZenTest --version "=4.8.3"`

I think this will solve you problem.

Cheers..!

Comment: please find the edited question and see where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Mine was causing trouble reporting the invalid .gemspec even after installing the specific version (and setting it as so in my Gemfile for good measure.) I ended up following the path given in the error and removing the incorrect gemspec file directly to quieten it. Yours would be at `/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec`

Comment: Remove the gemspec file `/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec`. 
Helpful comment from **Peter**

Comment: @ReNjITh.R -hey thanks a lot guys . but how should I remove the specific gemspec ? from command line ? I am very much new to ruby on rails in general.

Comment: @novice7: I am also a newbie in ROR. what i did was just removed the gemspec file. You just delete the `ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec` file.