# autotest failed with invalid gem spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

I am trying to run autotest, at one point it was working for me and then it stop. I have been following the ruby on rails tutorial.

```
lexi87$ autotest
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
loading autotest/rspec2
/Users/lexi87/rails_projects/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- autotest/growl (LoadError)
    from /Users/lexi87/rails_projects/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `load'
```

So if someone can provide the proper steps with getting autotest to work that would be great! Thanks

Comment: This answer worked for me, after struggling forever: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515879/2299459

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question: [Can't install ZenTest 4.8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488605/cant-install-zentest-4-8-4)
Looks like there's a bug in ruby gems. Suggested solution is downgrading zentest to 4.8.3

Comment: Thanks. I read it previously and followed the answer and it did not work. However when you referred me back to it I check the comments and I had to delete the gemspec file. Thanks